# React Native - Stacking app header content

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to stack content in the Navigation top bar that is being set using the `setOptions` method. However, I can't seem to stack vertically two pieces of content. Instead, I can only show a single piece of content. Keep in mind this header bar has no true navigation linking and is purely a "title" bar with text and imagery. It is also within the same component I use to actually create my navigation with `createBottomTabNavigator()`.

**What I would like is, pseudo-visually:**

```
<Text><Image><Text>
      <Text>
```

**Here is my code:**

```
navigation.setOptions({
  headerTitle: (
    <Text
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 16,
          lineHeight: 16,
        }}
      >
        Left Text{' '}
      </Text>
      <Image
        source={require('../assets/images/icon-large.png')}
        style={{ resizeMode: 'contain', width: 25, height: 25 }}
      />
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 16,
          lineHeight: 16,
        }}
      >
        {' '}
        Right Text
      </Text>
    </Text>
  ),
});
```

**which gives me, pseudo-visually:**

```
<Text><Image><Text>
```

Now, i've tried various layout's of `<View>` and `<Text>` and just cant seem to get the stacking visual im looking for. I've tried wrapping it all with a `<View>` and then a last `<Text>` but I believe the `headerTitle` property needs a `<Text>` or type string assigned to it.

Any suggestions how I can get another `<Text>` underneath (and centered) what I have already?

Comment: `<Text>` can not have children. Use a `<View>` as wrapper instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820589/2214188) and moving the navigation settings to the `Stack.Screen` I was able to get what I wanted. My problem seemed to be that I was trying to set the header options within `BottomTabNavigator`. Instead, if I passed in a custom "Header" component, it rendered the way I wanted it. Like so:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Scroll Rack"
      options={{ headerTitle: (props) => <Header /> }}
      component={BottomTabNavigator}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `View` which behaves as a row inside a `View` which behaves as a column. In the example below, the first `View` as `flexDirection: 'column'` as default.

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "#ff0000"}}>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between", backgroundColor: "#00ff00"}}>
    <Text>Left</Text>
    <Image
      source={{uri: "https://miro.medium.com/max/712/1*EnF9uIN_u2_X7ey24lB7Tg.png"}}
      style={{ resizeMode: 'contain', width: 25, height: 25 }}
    />
    <Text>Right</Text>
  </View>
  <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Bottom</Text>
</View>
```

[Here's a snack of it](https://snack.expo.io/@attaque/d0b643)

Comment: So I see the snack works but in that context its just a regular component whereas what i am doing is returned into the navigation options. The result is that your example nets the same result I am getting with my code.